# jQuery get toal from json

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have a Json with  a number of page and number of pictures on the page.
The default is 24 pages and if the user inputs a number go pages like 56 How can I create a loop to add the number off total pictures that will be in 56 pages.  Like “page 1+ page 2 + page 3 ….” the **loop should repate it self utiil it gets to 56 pages Thanks**

```
[{pagenumber: “1”, numofpic: "2"}, 
 {pagenumber: “2”, numofpic: "4"}, 
 {pagenumber: “3”, numofpic: "1"}, 
 {pagenumber: “4”, numofpic: "5"}, 
 {pagenumber: “5”, numofpic: "7"}]
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried. Stackoverflow isn't a free code writing service or a *"how to"* tutorial service. People will be happy to help you when you post your code that isn't working as expected. There are tutorials all over the web that should help you get started

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it -

```js
let pages = [{pagenumber: "1", numofpic: "2"}, 
 {pagenumber: "2", numofpic: "4"}, 
 {pagenumber: "3", numofpic: "1"}, 
 {pagenumber: "4", numofpic: "5"}, 
 {pagenumber: "5", numofpic: "7"}];
 
 let userSelectedPageNumber = 4;
 
 let totalNumOfPic = pages.filter(p => Number(p.pagenumber) <= userSelectedPageNumber).map(p => Number(p.numofpic)).reduce(function(acc, val) { return acc + val; });
 
 console.log(totalNumOfPic);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can simply add by using the classic method

let arr= [{pagenumber: “1”, numofpic: "2"}, 
 {pagenumber: “2”, numofpic: "4"}, 
 {pagenumber: “3”, numofpic: "1"}, 
 {pagenumber: “4”, numofpic: "5"}, 
 {pagenumber: “5”, numofpic: "7"}
 ect...]

 let  result=0;

for(let i=0; i<arr.length && arr.length<=enteredNo; i++){
    result += arr[i].b;
}

Or if you want the sum of the whole array you can use

    arr.reduce((a,b)=>{return a.numofpic + b.numofpic});
```